# Run time variable is not resolved inside style element in Sightly in AEM 6.2

Tags: html, css, aem, sightly, htl

I am trying to provide the background image to a div by creating a variable in sightly.

I am reading a property with sightly and when I supply this to style tag, it does not work.

here is the html

```
<sly data-sly-test.fileReference="${properties.title}" />

<div style="background: url(${fileReference}); background-position: center top;">
<p>${properties.title}</p>
```

When the page is rendered this is what I see

```
<div style="background: url(); background-position: center top;">
<p>my Title</p></div>
```

It means that `${properties.title}` inside the `<p>` tag is accepted but it does not work with inside style element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable is resolved just fine. The reason your `url()` value is empty is because you're not using the right [Display Context](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context). Also, the value, you're passing there, the string `"my Title"`, is not a valid URL (what you need to print) or a valid style token (what  usually gets rendered in a `style` attribute)

You'll notice that each of the following expressions renders an empty `url()` value:

```
<div style="background: url(${'cookies'});"></div>
<div style="background: url(${'cookies with chocolate chips'});"></div>

<!--/* both print background: url();*/-->
```

If we force the display context to allow any string, the value will be printed

```
<div style="background: url(${'cookies' @ context='unsafe'});">
</div>
<!--/* prints background: url(cookies);*/-->
```

In `script` and `style` contexts, HTL [requires the display context to be stated explicitly](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#113-context-sensitive). If it's not, the output is not rendered.

What you want to output to show a background image is the URL of an image. Let's try making this explicit:

```
<div style="background: url('${'/etc/designs/myapp/img/someimage.png' @ context='uri'}');">
</div>
<!--/* prints background: url('/etc/designs/myapp/img/someimage.png');*/-->
```

There, that does the trick!

Now, as a word of advice, try to avoid inline styling. You'll save yourself similar problems with display contexts and your CSS will be easier to maintain if it's part of a client library.

Comment: This is mostly correct, with just one clarification: *For style and script contexts, it is mandatory to set a context. If the context isn't set, the expression shouldn't output anything.*
See https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#113-context-sensitive

Comment: @Vlad thanks for the clarification, I thought the attribute used `styleToken`. Goes to show how rarely I use HTL to render CSS :) Anyway, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me--- adding @ context='styleToken'

```
<sly data-sly-test.fileReference="${properties.title}" />
<div style="background: url(${fileReference @ context='styleToken'}); background-position: center top;">
<p>${properties.title}</p>
```